# Can't define workheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Going crazy here. I use this definition of worksheet all the time. Copied every string to avoid typing errors. Still, the code below produces "Nothing" when I try to set FR worksheet. Pls help!

```
  Sub FindReplace()
  Dim FRep As Worksheet
  Dim c As Range
  Dim cText As TextBox
  Dim i As Integer

  Set FRep = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FindReplace")
  For i = 1 To 23
      cText = FRep.Cells(i, 3).Text
      FRep.Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
      FRep.Cells(i, 2).Value = cText
  Next i
```

Comment: Is this an actual snippet from your code? `FR` loses scope as soon as the sub ends, so it wouldn't be accessible outside the sub. Can you post a little more context?

Comment: It is actually as simple as this. FR never gets defined, remains as "Nothing". The rest of the code is running a very simple loop. Updated code is above.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see anything wrong, assuming that a sheet named "FindReplace" exists.  Try dropping a breakpoint on the line where you set the variable, dig down into the `ThisWorkbook` object and take a look at the `Worksheets` collection. If there's something unusual going on with this particular sheet, you may be able to find it there.

Answer (score 0):

The code as is seems correct. Make sure that "FindReplace" worksheet is in `ThisWorkbook`.

Also, you can try to get "FindReplace" worksheet by `CodeName` instead of by the name of the sheet. The advantage is that if the user changes the name of the worksheet, the `CodeName` will remain the same and you won't need to update your code to the new worksheet name.

```
Public Function GetWsFromCodeName(codeName As String, wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName = codeName Then
           Set GetWsFromCodeName = ws
           Exit For
        End If
    Next ws

End Function
```

Add this function in your code:

```
Sub FindReplace()
    Dim FRep As Worksheet
    Set FRep = GetWsFromCodeName("YourCodeName", ThisWorkbook)
```

Comment: Of course, I had another sub with the same name somewhere in the workbook, so it wasn't working because of the conflict. Thank you for your help!